# On debugging with breakpoints on all object creation, static methods and also constructors, I see strange control flow

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

This is my program here:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class Program
    {
        public Program():this(20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
        }

        private Program(int i) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }

        static Program()
        {
            int mess = 50;
            Console.WriteLine("Static");
        }

        Program p = new Program();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program(10);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am seeing that, the control of the program hits,

- Static constructor,
- then Main method,
- then "new Program(10)",
- then "Program p = new Program();"
- then "public Program():this(20)"
- and then looping back between last two things.

I have following concerns that I claim should happen:

1. It should straightaway go to `private Program(int i)` after the `new Program(10)`, but its not happening. STRANGE.
2. I feel no logic behind looping between last two calls. If I have to omit my question 1 above, and go on agreeing blindly on something that its flow is correct, I see no reason to loop this way between last two irrelevant calls as mentioned in the sequence above.

No logic I could understand.

Comment: [Static Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)  "is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced."

Comment: My concern was never behind "Why static constructor is called".

Comment: @Habib: By the way, let me ask you, static constructor is going to be hitted even before "HITTING STATIC MAIN METHOD"?

Comment: Read from the link in my first comment "The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the *static* constructor can run just about anywhere the JIT wants to run it, as long as it happens before an instance is created or static fields are accessed.

As for the instance constructor:

Field initializers are run *before* constructors; basically, it becomes:

```
private Program(int i)
{
    // base ctor
    base.ctor();
    // field initializers
    p = new Program();

    // now comes the ctor body
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
}
```

the `p = new Program(...)` is a stack overflow. Every `new Program` (using any constructor) wants to create, in the field initializer, a `new Program()`. Because the field initializer happens **before** the constructor body, you don't see any `Console.WriteLine` output before the stack explodes.

Comment: Thank you, I am afraid I do not fully follow you, but I saw that fields initialization takes place first, I agree with you partially, other things I don't understand what you saying. Thank you

Comment: I do not know or understand or agree why you have to put base.ctor. Ifind .NET illogical sometime. I am a Microsoft developer and never been on any other technologies.